# Highcharts show days of month dates in X axis (from JSON file). tickInterval: not work?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, highcharts

I have another issue with Highcharts graphs. A PHP file returns a JSON whith many elements, compounds of two fields (name: date,int:). I need Highcharts draw all dates of the month in the X axis.  The elements on JSON chain are all the same month.
I try whith many sintaxis of tickInterval (put 1, or put 24 * 3600 * 1000,...), but not works!
Thank you in advance!!!

NOTE: I tried to copy the code in jsFiddle, but does not work ... neither use jsFiddle  :( ... sorry!
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ram72/1/)

Thanks  wergeld!!
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ram72/2)

JSON chain returned from PHP file:

```
[{"name":"Sant Iscle 60","data":[[1398902400000,4],[1399939200000,1]]},{"name":"Sant Iscle 62","data":[[1399939200000,2]]},{"name":"Laboratorio Comp.","data":[[1400025600000,2]]}]
```

Javascript file:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
renderTo: 'divStatsGrupo',
plotBackgroundColor: null,
plotBorderWidth: null,
plotShadow: false,
type: 'column'
},

title: {
    text: tituloMes
},
    tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m/%Y',new Date(this.x)) + '<br/>' +'Alarmas: ' + this.y                       
    }   
    },

xAxis: {
     type: 'datetime',
tickInterval: 1,  //<------NOT WORKING?¿
    labels: {
    style: {
        fontSize: '13px',
        fontFamily: 'Arial,sans-serif'
        }
    },
    dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
     day: '%e. %b',
     }
        },
  yAxis: {
    tickInterval: 1,    
    title: {
    text: 'Total alarmas'
    },
    allowDecimals: false,
    min: 0
    },
series : data,                      
});
});
```

Image explicative:
[image]

Thank you very much in advance!!!

EDIT & SOLVED! ...Thanks Jerko again! ...see below answers for the solution!

Comment: Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ram72/2/. This does not have your fix - it just loads.

Comment: have you any idea why highcharts not shows me the dates (date) on the X axis?

Comment: Becasue you have 3 columsn with the same tick (the same x value) so ticks is single.

Comment: Thank you again Sebastian! I know, but I need to have several columns for the same day of the month. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You can use renderer to add custom text: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text

Comment: Thanks for your time and knowledge. Will investigate how to use the "renderer". Any clues? :)

Answer (score 4):

This is the common problem with columns and bars in Highcharts. You need to add `pointRange` under the `plotOptions`

Also `tickInterval` for one day is 24*3600*1000 not 1 (x-axis is in microseconds)

here is working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/nah67/3/

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointRange: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
    }
}
```

P.S. I removed some comments from your code, because they were distracting me :)

Comment: WoWw!! Jerko Returns! I'm impressed, really. That effective and lecture. At the end I will learn to use the Highcharts is thanks to you. Super-correct Answer!, yeahhh! thank you again Sir and amigo! ;)